# why my code has not a limit?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

That is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int vet[10], i;

    for(i=30; i<=45; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }

    for(i=30; i<=45; i++)
        printf(" %d ", vet[i]);

    for(i=30; i<=45; i++)
        printf(" %x", &vet[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I declared just 10 positions of int type on memory, but i get more, so what happened ?
it is a memory overflow ?

and the type %x is correctly to print the memory adress ?

the imput was:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10   /*It was to be stoped right here !?*/
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

and returned:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  /*I put space to indent*/

22ff6c 22ff70 22ff74 22ff78 22ff7c 22ff80 22ff84 22ff88 22ff8c 22ff90 22ff94 22ff98     22ff9c 22ffa0 22ffa4 22ffa8
```

Comment: W Wat? `for(i=30; i<=45; i++)`

Comment: `45 - 30 = 15`. Everything looks alright.

Comment: You're just overflowing the array

Comment: has difference if i put for(i=0; i<10; i++) or for(i=30; i<40; i++) ? Because is the same interval !  I thought the range that mattered, not the numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C language does not check bounds when you access arrays for reading or writing.  It is up to the program author to ensure that the program accesses only valid array elements.

In this case, you wrote values to memory addresses *outside* your declared array.  While you may sometimes get a segmentation violation (`SIGSEGV`) in this case, you may just get "lucky" -- really, unlucky -- and not encounter any problems at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't enforce array boundaries. Keeping within the limits is your responsibility in that language - it will let you do plainly wrong things, but it may crash at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Not only does the C language not check bounds on array accesses with respect to array size, which explains why you are successfully writing to the array 15 times, but C also does not have a mechanism for converting your range of 30 to 45 into the range of the first 10 (or 15?) elements of the array.

So, you are really attempting to write to the 31st through 46th element of the array `vet`, which has only 10 elements.

Answer (score 2):

C does not do bounds checking on arrays and you are accessing an array out of bounds. The possible valid indexes in the array are `[0,9]`, but you are accessing `[30,45]`.

You should modify your code to only access valid indexes:

```
int SIZE = 10;
int vet[SIZE]; 

//...

// not for( i = 30; i <= 45; i++ )
for( i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i ) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: has difference if i put `for(i=0; i<10; i++)` or `for(i=30; i<40; i++)` ? Because is the same interval !

Comment: @X0R40: Yes, there is a difference.  The size of the interval isn't the issue; the actual index value is the issue.  The only valid index values are 0 through 9; any other index value is outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @X0R40; YES. In second case you are accessing array out of bound and it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, I declared an int value, in this case, `vet[10]`, so the operation system gave me a memory adress, let's suppose `0x100`, so, the memory reserved by the OS for me, is `0x100` to `0x100 + 10*sizeof(int)` , then, `0x100 thought 0x140`, and if i access the vet[1], actually, i will accessing the memory `0x108 trought 0x112(the range of it)`. Is that correct ?

Comment: @X0R40 Close.  `vet` is `0x100` to `0x100 + 10*sizeof(int) - 1`.  Also note: `int` size could be 2,4,8, etc.

Comment: @chux sorry, but i didn't get it, `0x100 to 0x100 + 10*sizeof(int) - 1` why `-1` ?

Comment: @X0R40 Let's assume `sizeof(int) == 4` and use your example.  `vet[0]` is in `0x100, 0x101, 0x102, 0x103`.  `vet[1]` is in `0x104, 0x105, 0x106, 0x107`.  `vet[2]` is in `0x108, 0x109, 0x10A, 0x10B`.  `vet` is in `0x100, 0x101, 0x102, ... 0x127`.   Location `0x128` and beyond are used for some _other_ variables.

Comment: @chux Thanks very much ! I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

C is perfectly happy to let you read from and write to an array past the bounds you set (10, in this case).

Reading past the limit just gives you garbage;  writing past it will do all kinds of crazy things and generally crash your program (or,  if you are unlucky, overwrite your entire hard drive).

You were lucky with this program,  but you should not keep doing that.  In C, you are responsible for enforcing the limits of your arrays yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`int vet[10]` declares a block of ten integers in memory.  These memory locations are accessed via `vet[0]` through `vet[9]`.  Any other access to memory through `vet` is undefined behavior.  Absolutely anything could be within that memory, and you can easily corrupt the rest of your program execution.  The compiler trusts you to know better than what you were doing.

As @NigelHarper correctly points out, `%p` is the official way of printing pointers.  It prints in hexadecimal.  Pointers could print in decimal, but the number itself is meaningless.  Hexadecimal makes the printing more concise, and just as easy to see differences from one address to the next.

It is also possible to use `%x` for printing a pointer, since all that does is take a value and print it in hexadecimal form.

Comment: The standard conversion specifier for pointers is %p. %x (and %d) may work but it's by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @NigelHarper Thanks, that was a bad mistake on my part.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

C Language doesn't have support to check the out of bound array accesses. IN c++, if you try to access out of bound array memory location, it will generate Segmentation Fault which causes your process to terminate. As, C doesn't allow it, it is expected behavior.